# How to format color to only few characters of chart's datalabel?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a pie chart with category and and percentage as datalabel. I want only category name as red colored but not percentage. I want this be done in VBA. It works while using `font.bold`.

```
Sub ex()
    Dim Ch As ChartObject
    Set Ch = Sheet1.ChartObjects(1)
    Dim s As Series
    Set s = Ch.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

    Dim p As Point
    Set p = s.Points(4)
    p.DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 1).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbRed
End Sub
```

Comment: I just tested your code and it works? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

If your category names are not of the same size they you may want to try something like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim objChart As ChartObject
    Set objChart = Sheet1.ChartObjects(1)
    
    Dim Chrt As Chart
    Set Chrt = objChart.Chart
    
    Dim objSeries As Series
    Set objSeries = Chrt.SeriesCollection(1)

    Dim p As Point
    '~~> Change this to the releavant point
    Set p = objSeries.Points(3)
        
    Dim CatValueLength As Long
    
    With p.DataLabel.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange
       .InsertChartField msoChartFieldCategoryName, "", 1
       
       '~~> If separator is newline then change
       '    ", "    to     "" & Chr(10) & ""
       '~~> Or if it something else then change accordingly
       .InsertAfter ", "
       
       '~~> Get the category value, length so that we can insert % values
       CatValueLength = Len(p.DataLabel.Text)
       
       '~~> Include the percentage
       .InsertChartField msoChartFieldPercentage, "", CatValueLength
       
       '~~> Color the category name
       .Characters(1, CatValueLength).Font.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbRed
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]